# Is there a more efficient method to using Nested IF's in Python

Tags: python, nested-if

I want to find a way to make it more efficient to check whether an input is = to one number or another, but the only way i've learnt and can see is using nested if's in python.

```
def menu():
    while type(x) != int or x < 0 or x > 46:
        try:
            x = int(input("\nEnter a valid menu choice: "))
        except:
            print("\nInvalid input...\n")
    if x == 1:
        max1()
    elif x == 2:

    elif x == 3:

    elif x == 4:
```

This is my code design for a simple menu function to call upon other functions with a user's input, however i need 46 more `if x == n`.

Is there a faster way than doing an `elif x == n+1` every line?

Comment: There are other options, such as a dispatch dict (constructed **outside** the function if you really need it to be efficient), but it seems to me like the 46-item menu might be a deeper problem.

Comment: The "best" solution depends on how different the menu items are from one another

Answer (score 2):

Use a dictionary to hold the references to the functions, then use `x` to get the right function, then call it:

```
{1: max1, 2: whatever, 3: something_else}[x]()
```

In this case you're selecting the right function with an integer, so you could also use a list:

```
[max1, whatever, something_else][x-1]()
```

But I prefer the dictionary because it is easier to read: you can easily find the function associated with `13` if you need to change it.

N.B. there are no "nested `if`s" in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary of integers to functions:

```
function_mapping = {
    1: max1,
    2: max2,
    ...
    n: maxn
}

function_mapping[x]()
```

If your functions are named this way, there are "hackish" ways of constructing this dictionary, e.g.

```
function_mapping = {i: globals()['max' + str(i)] for i in range(1,n+1)}
```

Answer (score 0):

If none of these branches can be abstracted/combined, something like this could be useful:

```
def max1():
  pass # your block body

def error():
  pass # handle lookup failure

{1:max1
,2:...
}.get(x,error)()
```

Python dictionaries should be hashmaps so the lookup should be roughly constant time, especially for integer keys.